# How do I turn off autoformat OpenCalc / OpenOffice Spreadsheets

Tags: conditional-formatting, openoffice, spreadsheet, cells, cell-format

**Without context and background:** Read the title, How do I turn off AutoCorrect in OpenCalc, specifically time, preferably turn off all AutoFormat.

I am using a spreadsheet to track how fast my online store (in a browser game) runs out of stock, keep track of the quantities I buy with at various prices, keep track of profit per unit* (example below) and also a column to track my profits after restocking efforts, if there are Pure Profits then I track where I spend them (diversifying income.)

(say I purchased 52 units of X for 22Cr/ea and I sell 52 units of X for 30Cr/ea those 52 units have a 8Cr/unit profit, but not all of my stock will have the same profit per unit as I have to buy from different sources.)

This is all fine and dandy, except when I type out a time, I sold 1 batch tonight, stocked at 15:30 (how I type so it fits in one cell) and when I check at 10:11pm (22:11) it was all sold out. I can type 15:30-22:11 just fine, but in the cell below it (for my 2nd run) I type out 22:23 and OpenCalc auto formats, and I can't figure out why and I see posts saying how to turn off AutoFormat for OpenDoc/OpenOffice but no idea how to turn off for OpenCalc. Thanks for any help.